# Devolver recordsets manteniendo el tipo de dato, SQL server Nodejs

Tags: sql, nodejs, express, mssql

tengo una inquietud, cuando hago consultas a la base de datos SQL, el recordsets me muestra en formato json, y se pierde el tipo de datos, ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo Id, es bigint, y quisiera que mantuviera el tipo de datos, es decir, Int o Numero. Ejemplo: Que resultado sea; Categoria : 1 no Categoria : "1".

Es decir evitar que se pierda el tipo de campo. Muchas gracias.

```
let query = await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM Listas')
```

Comment: El driver de `mssql` para NodeJS mantiene el tipo de dato o hace el *cast* adecuado si es necesario. ¿Puedes mostrar el DDL de tu tabla `listas`? Toma en cuenta que BigInt no es un tipo de dato propio de JavaScript, por lo cual la conversión a `Number` no es posible. El valor [entero más alto que puedes representar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) en Javascript es del orden de 2^53, esto es: `9007199254740991` o sea 9 mil billones. ¿Tu tabla tendrá más de dicha cantidad de registros?

Comment: Mi comentario anterior es para preguntar si es realmente necesario que tu campo `Id` sea de tipo `bigint` en SQL Server. Tal vez, si necesitas almacenar más de 2^31 registros (2.147.483.647), el uso de tipos numéricos no se justificaría, tal vez usar `varchar` sea lo más adecuado, ya que ¿vas a realizar operaciones aritméticas con el valor de `Id`? Supongo que no, por lo tanto, ¿para qué guardarlo como valor numérico?